# Convergence of infinite series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k\ln(k)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In a recent assignment, as an intermediate step, I need to show that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k\ln(k)}$ converges.
It is not hard to see that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\ln(k)}$ is divergent, therefore I think one has to deal with the sum of alternating sequence directly. However, I am stuck and don't know how to proceed.
Thanks in advance for anyone that is kind to help!

Comment: alternating series test

Comment: Leibniz criterion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for some reason, you do not want to use the Leibniz criterion, you can group your sum in pairs:
$$
a_n = \frac{(-1)^{2n}}{2n\log(2n)}+\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\log(2n+1)}
$$
is positive, and $a_n < \frac{1}{n^2}$ so $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: Thank you! This is really an interesting way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The series converges, and it can be proven using the [Leibniz criterion for alternating series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

The criterion analyzes sums of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$$ where $a_i\geq 0$. The criterion says that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$ and the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing, then the sum converges. In your case, $a_k=\frac{1}{k\ln k}$ which satisfies both conditions (it's decreasing and has a limit of $0$), so the series converges.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing it out! I wasn't aware of the criterion at first place. It is surely a useful and interesting result!

Answer (score 1):

You may also couple adjacent terms:
$$ 0<\frac{1}{2k\log(2k)}-\frac{1}{(2k+1)\log(2k+1)} = \frac{2k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)+\log(2k+1)}{2k(2k+1)\log(2k)\log(2k+1)}<\frac{1}{k^2} $$
and recall that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: Thank you! I think the answer is similar to the one provided by GEdger. Truly interesting!